What kind of matching network this is?
These networks are found in commercially available yagis with folded dipole driven element. I wander what theoretical model is used to design them? Appearently two parallel transmission lines branch off from feedpoint and central from one is shorted to gnd from other at the antenna connection point.
Is this a shorted stub 1:4 tuner?


Can you include a photo of the other side?
